# Trouble installing ubuntu server on virtualbox (osx)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to install lucid lynx 10.04.2 server on a virtualbox on snow leopard.

I have 2 server iso files freshly downloaded one i386 and one 64bit.

When I try to start the virtual machine with either one set to be the cd drive I'm getting the same error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ub.
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT).
Unknown error creating VM (VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT).
```

Couldn't find anything on it on google so I'm trying to see if anyone else has dealt with this issue. Thanks much in advance!

edit: just downloaded the 32bit desktop edition to same avail

edit2: ran Disk Utility' replair permissions then restarted. New error VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE (instead of VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well now that disk utility seems to have done something and changed the error, you need to change your permissions back to 755 or something so that the VM is no longer world writable, i.e. follow the text of the error...

Comment: Nice, thanks for helping a newbie out... I wish I could accept both of your answers. Still I wish I didn't have to run the Disk Util...

Comment: Glad you're up and running! Most likely something got fudged on the install of VB, and some files didn't get chowned properly in /Library or something.  That's the beauty of Disk Util and OS X.  On Windows you'd probably still be pulling your hair out chasing obscure error messages...:)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like access rights issues.
Check where you do store your VMs and their VHDs and how the permissions for these folders and files are set.
Then check with which user you execute VirtualBox and if the granted permissions match.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've gone through the ~/VirtualBox VMs folder and changed permissions to 777 for all files and folders there to no change

Comment: I think you are definitely right about the issue, I just can't find the specific content that's lacking permission